# Terraform / Heroku not finding 'web' process in heroku/ruby buildpack

Tags: heroku, terraform

I'm getting an error in Terraform:

> Error: Patch "https://api.heroku.com/apps/coderdojo-contentful-staging/formation/web": Couldn't find that process type (web).
> │
> │ with heroku_formation.coderdojo_contentful_staging_formation[0],
> │ on terraform.tf line 41, in resource "heroku_formation" "coderdojo_contentful_staging_formation":
> │ 41: resource "heroku_formation" "coderdojo_contentful_staging_formation" {

from these lines from my `terraform.tf` file:

```terraform
resource "heroku_formation" "coderdojo_contentful_staging_formation" {
  count    = length(var.formations)
  app      = heroku_app.coderdojo_contentful_staging.name
  type     = lookup(var.formations[count.index], "type")
  quantity = lookup(var.formations[count.index], "quantity")
  size     = lookup(var.formations[count.index], "size")
}
```

which rely on these lines in my `terraform.tfvars` file:

```terraform
formations = [
  {
    type     = "web"
    size     = "standard-1x"
    quantity = "1"
  }
]

buildpacks = [
  "heroku/ruby"
]
```

Searching the documentation online (e.g. [buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) and [heroku-buildpack-ruby](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby)) it appears that the web process type comes from either the buildpack, or the `Procfile`.

Another project works fine with a very similar setup (i.e. no `Procfile`), but with the addition of a `heroku/nodejs` buildpack. I tried adding that build pack but got the same error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Another project works fine with a very similar setup (i.e. no `Procfile`), but with the addition of a `heroku/nodejs` buildpack. I tried adding that build pack but got the same error.

The `heroku/nodejs` buildpack falls back to the start script defined in the `package.json` if no `Procfile` is present. I suspect your other project that uses that buildpack has a start script. The Ruby buildpack [has no such default](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-applications-process-types).

If your app doesn't require Node.js, don't add the Node.js buildpack. Instead, add a `Procfile` to the root of your repository that tells Heroku how to run your app, e.g.

```
web: bundle exec ruby path/to/some/script.rb
```

This defines a `web` process that runs `bundle exec ruby ruby path/to/some/script.rb`.

Comment: Thanks.  I have been looking for the _Procfile_ in the wrong place. I was looking in the repo where we keep our Terraform scripts, but it is in the Rails project's repo. Thanks Chris.